# mysql using AS and showing php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this SQL statement that works fine in mysql, but I am unable to get it to work on a php page and show the data the same way it does in mysql?

`$NewSql="SELECT r1.ticket, r1.status, r1.time, r2.ticket, r2.status, r2.time
FROM repair_status AS r1, repair_status AS r2
WHERE r1.status =  'New'
AND r2.status =  'Fixed'
AND r1.ticket = r2.ticket";`

When I try and show I use something like:

```
while($New = mysql_fetch_array($NewSql)){

echo $New['r1.status'].$New['r1.ticket'].$New['r2.ticket'].$New['r2.status']."<br>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

yuou should supply an `ALIAS` to avoid ambiguity for columns names which happens to be the same on both tables and the alias will then be used to fetch the data, ex

```
SELECT r1.ticket r1Ticket,  
       r2.ticket r2Ticket, .....
FROM ....
```

in PHP

```
 echo $New['r1Ticket'].$New['r2Ticket'].....
```